# How do I create a project (dependency) that I can share between other projects?

Tags: typescript, module, dependencies

I have a project A

```
// projectA/tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2022",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./build",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "strict": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
    }
}
```

```
// projectA/package.json
{
  "name": "project_a",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

```
// projectA/src/main.ts
export function projectAHello() {
    console.log("Hello from project A!")
}
```

I am trying to import it in project B;

```
// projectB/tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2022",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./build",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "strict": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
    }
}
```

```
// projectB/package.json
{
  "name": "project_b",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "project_a": "../projectA"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

```
// projectB/src/main.ts
import projectAHello from "project_a/main"
projectAHello()
```

But when I run the compiler in projectB, it gives me this:

```
❯ ./node_modules/.bin/tsc
src/main.ts:1:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'project_a/main' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

So how do I configure project A properly, so that project B can use its code?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `npm link` to locally link packages. You can check the docs [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link).

Comment: That's easy enough, but my question is how do I code the "linked" package so that I can use it in project B?

Comment: You need to import it like any other npm package you have installed.

`import projectAHello from "project_a"`

Comment: Already doing that, please look at my question.

Comment: Did you try linking project A with npm link, before importing it?